# Implementing Facebook iOS SDK - no "fbDidLogin" callback

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, sdk

I was following integration steps from official FB documentation and have implemented "login" and "post to wall" features of the SDK, and everything ok, but the problem is that its working only if Im using main app delegate .h/.m files.
   But currently I need to put it into another .h/.m file - login works, but "fbDidLogin" callback never calls, I used NSLog to check. Im not very good with ObjC, and using a game-engine, so I guess I missed some private/public declaration stuff etc.. Can you please lead me in right direction to fix it? Thanks in advance!

code looks like this:

.h

```
#import "FBConnect.h"
...
@interface S3DEngine_EAGLView : UIView <UITextFieldDelegate, FBSessionDelegate>
{   

@public Facebook *facebook;

@private
...
    EAGLContext                    *pEAGLContext                ;
...
}
@property NSTimeInterval iAnimationInterval;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *achievementsDictionary;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;
...
```

.m

```
@implementation S3DEngine_EAGLView
...
@synthesize facebook;
...
- (void)fbDidLogin {
}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be fired in case you assign the Facebook delegate to your viewController .. and thats what I think because you are defining a property for the Facebook instance , are you assigning it to the one in the app delegate ? if so just move the Facebook implementation from the app delegate to your viewController.